# Error "No known class method for selector 'Hello:'" in custom-made framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, compiler-errors, ios-frameworks

I am making a framework for a company and I have completed all the code. I'm now trying to package it into a framework.  As a test I made a method with this name: `-(void)Hello:(NSString *)worldText;`

When I try to call it in the application with the framework using this code `[CompanyMobile Hello:@"World"];`, I'm getting a compiler error which says

> No known class method for selector 'Hello:'

The .m in my framework is as follows:

```
#import "Hello.h"

@implementation Hello

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)Hello:(NSString *)world {

}

@end
```

The .h in my framework is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Hello : NSObject
-(void)Hello:(NSString *)world;
@end
```

The .h in my application

```
//
//  FMWK_TESTViewController.h
//  FMWK TEST
//
//  Created by Sam on 6/15/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <companyMobile/Hello.h>
@interface FMWK_TESTViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

The .m in my application

```
//
//  FMWK_TESTViewController.m
//  FMWK TEST
//
//  Created by Sam Baumgarten on 6/15/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FMWK_TESTViewController.h"

@implementation FMWK_TESTViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [Badgeville Hello:@"Sam"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You defined `Hello:` as an instance method, but you're sending `Hello:` to the class. To define a class method, you write `+ (void)Hello:` rather than `- (void)Hello:`.

Answer (score 11):

please refer to : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html

to answer your question,  change

```
@interface Hello : NSObject
-(void)Hello:(NSString *)world;
@end
```

to

```
@interface CompanyMobile : NSObject{
}
+(void)Hello:(NSString *)world;
@end
```

and call the method `[CompanyMobile Hello:@"world"];`