# No known class method for selector 'circleOfButtons:buttonSize:radius:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, selector

A function `circleOfButtons:buttonSize:radius:` in `SGView` (*below*) is called from `ParentView` and I want `ParentView` to define the values inside `SGView` whenever `ParentView` sends a message to `SGView`.

This is the implementation file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import “ParentView.h"
#import "SGView.h"

@implementation ParentView : UIView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self                        = [super initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    if (self) {

    self.backgroundColor        = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    int     count               = 5;
    CGFloat size                = 80.0;
    CGFloat radius              = 68;

    SGView *myView              = [SGView circleOfButtons:count buttonSize:size radius:radius];
    [self addSubview:myView];
    }
return self;
}
```

SGView arranges multiple UIButtons in a circle and is essentially like this

```
#import "SGView.h"

@implementation SGView : UIView

+(id)circleOfButtons:(int)buttonCount buttonSize:(CGFloat)buttonSize circleRadius:(CGFloat)circleRadius
    {
    UIView *multipleViews       = [self new];

    // … circular geometry …
    [multipleViews addSubview:circleButton];
    }
    return multipleViews;
}
@end
```

The error message - at the line `SGView *myView` - is:

> No known class method for selector
>   'circleOfButtons:buttonSize:radius:'

My guess is the compiler wants a declaration in the interface. I’m working through [these tutorials](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) trying to decide what the interface file should look like and though there are 6 SO questions that may already have answered my question, only [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11864651/2348597) had an example that seemed vaguely relevant.

This is my interface file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SGView.h"

@interface ParentView : UIView {
}

+(id)circleOfButtons:(int)buttonCount buttonSize:(CGFloat)buttonSize circleRadius:(CGFloat)circleRadius;

@end
```

Can anyone please give an example showing what this interface file should look like ? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is `SGView.h` (revised)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SGView : UIView {
}
+(id)circleOfButtons:(int)buttonCount buttonSize:(CGFloat)buttonSize circleRadius:(CGFloat)circleRadius;
@end
```

I also noticed if the statement

```
        SGView *myView              = [SGView circleOfButtons:count buttonSize:size radius:radius];
```

is changed to

```
        SGView *myView              = [self circleOfButtons:count buttonSize:size radius:radius];
```

the error changes to

> *No visible @interface for 'ParentView' declares the selector 'circleOfButtons:buttonSize:radius:'*

it was previously

> No known class method for selector 'circleOfButtons:buttonSize:radius:'

Comment: you have to decalre +(id)circleOfButtons:(int)buttonCount buttonSize:(CGFloat)buttonSize circleRadius:(CGFloat)circleRadius; in SGView.h class

Comment: Jen, @ron27, I declared it in SGView and removed the declaration in ParentView but the error persists

Comment: what do you write in SGView.h file ?

Comment: Jen, see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
  SGView *myView              = [SGView circleOfButtons:count buttonSize:size radius:radius];
```

It should be

```
SGView *myView              = [SGView circleOfButtons:count buttonSize:size circleRadius:radius];
```

Comment: Jen, I'm now adding a delegate to make the buttons work. if you can spare a moment, you might have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/43151212/2348597

Answer (score 0):

Declare `+(id)circleOfButtons:(int)buttonCount buttonSize:(CGFloat)buttonSize circleRadius:(CGFloat)circleRadius` in `SGView.h` file.
Now you will get the method in `ParentView` class.

Happy coding :) .