# Member reference base type 'Class' is not a structure or union - has the Fixit led me in the right direction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, delegates, target-action

I’m trying to make a `delegate` that will send messages from `UIButtons` within a custom `UIView` called `SGView` and am a bit out of my depth following the error messages. I recently learned how to get a [delegate to send messages successfully from within an instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42994677/2348597).

`SGView` includes a class method that arranges multiple `UIButtons`in a circle and was designed to be used by different `UIViews.` [The geometry works when the method is called from a parent UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43140240/2348597). I have now declared the `delegate` by adding `@protocol` and `@property` to the class method declaration

like so ...

**SGView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SGViewDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button;
@end

@interface SGView : UIView {
    }
    +(id)circleOfButtons:(int)buttonCount buttonSize:(CGFloat)buttonSize circleRadius:(CGFloat)circleRadius;

@property (assign) id<SGViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**SGView.m** is essentially like this

```
#import "SGView.h"

    @implementation SGView : UIView

    +(id)circleOfButtons:(int)buttonCount buttonSize:(CGFloat)buttonSize circleRadius:(CGFloat)circleRadius
    {
    UIView *multipleViews       = [self new];

    // … circular geometry …

    [circleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [multipleViews addSubview:circleButton];
    }
    return multipleViews;
    }
    @end
```

The moment I change the target from `self` to `self.delegate` in the target action statement *above,* Xcode reports three errors

> Definition of 'objc_class' must be imported from module
>   'ObjectiveC.runtime' before it is required
>
> No member named 'delegate' in 'struct objc_class'
>
> Member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer; did you mean
>   to use '->'?

Xcode offers a Fixit for the last of these

```
    Fixit Replace”.” with “->”
```

By accepting the Fixit I removed the three issues and introduced another

> Member reference base type 'Class' is not a structure or union

If this Fixit has lead me in the right direction, what exactly should I be doing next ?

I need to ask this question to make sense of what might seem a straight forward problem before diving back into the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW7) and [these tutorials](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) trying to solve it. Any help is most appreciated. Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

This can be found in my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the class method to an instance method appears to have solved my problem.

This involved making the class method `+(id)circleOfButtons:... etc` into an instance method (`-(id)circleOfButtons:... etc`) in both `.m` and `.h` files. It was also necessary to change the call in the parent `UIView` from

```
    SGView *sgView              = [SGView circleOfButtons:count buttonSize:size circleRadius:radius];
```

to

```
    SGView *sgView              = [[SGView alloc] circleOfButtons:count buttonSize:size circleRadius:radius];
```

and change the declaration in `SGView` from

```
    UIView *multipleViews       = [self new];
```

to

```
    UIView *multipleViews       = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

`SGView` can be now reused from different `UIViews` that change the number and size of `UIButtons` arranged in a circle. The delegate in `SGView` also allows each button to send a tagged message to a method in another class - in my case the `ViewController.`

The complete listing is included below and I'd welcome suggestions or improvements from others with more experience in OO programming.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIContentContainer> {
    }
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FamilyView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad                                             {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"load FamilyView");

    CGRect rect             = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    float  statusBarHeight  = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
    CGRect screenFrame      = CGRectMake(0, statusBarHeight, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - statusBarHeight);
    self.view               = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: screenFrame];

    FamilyView *cv          = [[FamilyView alloc]initWithFrame:screenFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:cv];    
}


    - (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button                          {
    NSLog(@"Button %ld clicked.", (long int)[button tag]);

    switch (button.tag) {
        case 1:
        //            [self goToFamily1];
            break;
        case 2:
        //            [self goToFamily2];
            break;
        case 3:
        //            [self goToFamily3];
            break;
        case 4:
        //            [self goToFamily4];
            break;
        case 5:
        //            [self goToFamily5];
            break;
        default:
        //            [self goToHelp];
            break;
        }
    }
    @end
```

**FamilyView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SGView.h"

    @interface FamilyView : UIView {
    }
@end
```

**FamilyView.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FamilyView.h"
#import "SGView.h"

    @implementation FamilyView : UIView

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self                                    = [super initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    if (self) {

    self.backgroundColor                    = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    int     count                           = 5;  //16;
    CGFloat size                            = 80; //41;
    CGFloat radius                          = 68; //105;

    SGView *sgView                          = [[SGView alloc] circleOfButtons:count buttonSize:size circleRadius:radius];
    [self addSubview:sgView];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**SGView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @protocol SGViewDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button;
    @end

    @interface SGView : UIView {
    }

      -(id)circleOfButtons:(int)buttonCount buttonSize:(CGFloat)buttonSize circleRadius:(CGFloat)circleRadius;

    @property (assign) id<SGViewDelegate> delegate;

    @end
```

**SGView.m**

```
#import "SGView.h"

    @implementation SGView : UIView

    -(id)circleOfButtons:(int)buttonCount buttonSize:(CGFloat)buttonSize circleRadius:(CGFloat)circleRadius
    {
    UIView *multipleViews                   = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    CGPoint screenCentre;
    CGPoint buttonCentre;

    screenCentre.x                          = CGRectGetWidth  ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) / 2;
    screenCentre.y                          = CGRectGetHeight ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) / 2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= buttonCount; i++) {
        CGFloat radians                     = 2 * M_PI * i / buttonCount;
        CGFloat arcStartPoint               = - M_PI / 2; // first point clockwise after 12 o'clock
        buttonCentre.x                      = screenCentre.x + circleRadius * cos(radians + arcStartPoint);
        buttonCentre.y                      = screenCentre.y + circleRadius * sin(radians + arcStartPoint);

        CGPoint target                      = CGPointMake(buttonCentre.x, buttonCentre.y);
        CGFloat x                           = screenCentre.x - buttonSize / 2;
        CGFloat y                           = screenCentre.y - buttonSize / 2;
        CGFloat wide                        = buttonSize;
        CGFloat high                        = buttonSize;
        UIButton *circleButton              = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, wide, high)];

        [circleButton setTag:i];
        [circleButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        circleButton.clipsToBounds          = YES;
        circleButton.layer.masksToBounds    = NO;
        circleButton.layer.shadowOffset     = CGSizeMake(-15, 20);
        circleButton.layer.shadowRadius     = 5;
        circleButton.layer.shadowOpacity    = 0.0;
        circleButton.layer.borderWidth      = 0.25f;
        circleButton.layer.cornerRadius     = buttonSize/2;
        circleButton.layer.borderColor      = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        circleButton.backgroundColor        = UIColor.whiteColor;
        [circleButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        if (buttonCount > 25) {
            [circleButton setTitleColor: [UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            } else {
            [circleButton setTitleColor: [UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        [multipleViews addSubview:circleButton];

    // animation 1
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        circleButton.transform              = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        circleButton.center                 = screenCentre;
        }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];

    // animation 2
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        circleButton.transform              = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        circleButton.center                 = target;
        }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    }
    return multipleViews;
}
@end
```