# IOS Build fails with "ARC Semantic Issue"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

[image]

Struggling to figure out what the issue is I've been googling for a while now but haven't been able to figure out why the build fails with this error.

Also tried cleaning and rebuilding. Done a pod install and pod update but doesn't seem to fix anything.

Would love some advice on where to go forward from here.

Comment: Why name of class is "SDImageIOCoder 2.m"? Did you change it? I didn't find to in SDWebImage repo.

Comment: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/e7b87885ae3d73b3ed9e2c28f3c5a164305f9ef8/SDWebImage/Core/SDImageIOCoder.m

Comment: I've just ended up deleting it now get this error -> 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createFrameAtIndex:source:scale:preserveAspectRatio:thumbnailSize:` is probably declared as an instance method, but you are calling it directly on the class instead of on an instance of this class.

Make sure that it has the right declaration, `+ (UIImage*)createFrameAtIndex:...` for a class method, or `- (UIImage*)createFrameAtIndex:...` for an instance method.

See [Error "No known class method for selector 'Hello:'" in custom-made framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361704/error-no-known-class-method-for-selector-hello-in-custom-made-framework) details.

Comment: thank you for the answer! I'm getting another error now with my google maps :(

Comment: Any ideas what this could be from? 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found -> #import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>